# What does the dotted white box around a variable name indicate?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I've just noticed that sometimes a dotted white box that appears around variables while typing their name. What is this supposed to indicate? A quick Google only turned up lots of completely unrelated results

In the below image the cursor is at the end of `StatusByte`, which has just been typed in and which previously used a different name. The change is not done as a "Rename" (`Ctrl+R, Ctrl+R`) and the variable is not yet used anywhere else at this point. The box disappears, not when I move the cursor away, but when the cursor is moved elsewhere *and* typing begins.

I am using VS 2017 15.3.1, only having recently updated from a 15.2.x version. I don't think this was occurring in that previous version but may just not have noticed it. This shows in Visual Basic, I have not had chance to check with other languages yet.

[image: screenshot of code in MSVS editor showing box around variable name]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This box appears while you are changing a variable, method, class or namespace name in Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2017 for C# and Visual Basic.

(I have an extension that hides it: [Plain Rename](https://vlasovstudio.com/plain-rename/).)

Comment: is that all it is, simply an indicator that you're changing a Name?

Comment: It probably also indicates that the Rename quick action (light bulb, Ctrl+.) is currently available to update all references to this variable.

Comment: It does nothing but mess me up. I'll click somewhere and start typing only to find that the text in this dashed box gets changed, usually to the first text character I type. Then I have to go back and undo it. Confusing.

Comment: just hover over the quick action blue screw driver tool on the left and select RENAME this method and that will get rid of the dotted square box. Or just right click on it and select RENAME.